# Android studio is exiting afer few seconds of start

Tags: 14.04, jdk, android-studio

I installed the android studio ppa from https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/  after that one day its work fine for me but, unexpectedly from second day its closing automatic after 2, 3 seconds. find lot of i got few queries in that regarding the JDK problem is one, but its very well in my case I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I also shared the JDK info on terminal screen, please help me in this case , Thanks in advance.

```
sachin@sachin-Aspire-5742:~$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: Is a directory
sachin@sachin-Aspire-5742:~$ update-alternatives --display java
java - manual mode
link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 2
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java'.
sachin@sachin-Aspire-5742:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you noticed this:

> Note: If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to
> install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
> ```
>
> From: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Maybe you're missing these libs or your Adnroid Studio is using wrong JDK.